# Resource Pool implementation with ReentrantLock and Condition

Tags: java, locking

The Resource Pool is similar to the implementation of a semaphore. It takes the class type of the resource and number of resource pools associated with it as the constructor parameters. There is a small ambiguity here, when the `Resource` instance is created it uses reflection, but when we require the resource name a call to `getName()` from the `ResourceA` interface is sufficient. Each Resource has a corresponding resource pool entry in the `resource_pool_table Map`. The `poolAvailable` `Condition` variable will signal all waiting threads when a resource is released back into the pool. Correspondingly threads will wait on the Resource Pool lock condition until an object pool is available for the resource with the `resourceName`.

```
package concurrency;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

interface ResourceA {
    String getName();
}

interface ResourceExceptionHandler {
    void handle(Exception exc);
}

class ResourceExceptionHandlerImpl implements ResourceExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception exc) {

    }
}

class ResourceCreationException extends Exception {
}

public class ResourcePool<R extends ResourceA> {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition poolAvailable = lock.newCondition();
    private int num_resource_pools;
    private final Hashtable<String, Vector<R>> resource_pool_table = new Hashtable<String, Vector<R>>();
    private final Class<R> resourceClass;
    private final ResourceExceptionHandler resourceExceptionHandler = new ResourceExceptionHandlerImpl();

    private R createResource(String str) {
        R resource = null;
        try {
            resource = resourceClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class)
                    .newInstance(str);

            if (resource == null)
                throw new ResourceCreationException();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            resourceExceptionHandler.handle(e);
        }
        return resource;
    }

    public ResourcePool(Class<R> resourceClass, int num_resource_pools) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            this.resourceClass = resourceClass;
            this.num_resource_pools = num_resource_pools;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public R acquireResource(String resourceName) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (num_resource_pools <= 0)
                poolAvailable.await();

            --num_resource_pools;

            Vector<R> pool = resource_pool_table.get(resourceName);

            if (pool != null) {
                int size = pool.size();
                if (size > 0)
                    return pool.remove(size - 1);
            }
            return createResource(resourceName);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void releaseResource(R resource) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            String resourceName = resource.getName();
            Vector<R> pool = resource_pool_table.get(resourceName);
            if (pool == null) {
                pool = new Vector<R>();
                resource_pool_table.put(resourceName, pool);
            }
            pool.addElement(resource);
            ++num_resource_pools;
            poolAvailable.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

**JUnit tests**

```
 package concurrency;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

/*
 * Test Resource 
 */

class SomeResource implements ResourceA {
    private String name;
    public SomeResource(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

/*
 * Test cases for Resource Pool
 */
public class ResourcePoolTest extends TestCase {

  /*Checks the number of the resources in the Resource Table.
    Resource is created only if needed.*/
    public void testIsEmptyBeforeResourceAcquired() throws Exception {
        ResourcePool<SomeResource> resPool = new ResourcePool<SomeResource>(
                SomeResource.class, 5);
        assertTrue(resPool.isEmpty("A"));
    }

 /* Checks if the number of resouces in the Resource Table is equal to the 
  * maximum number of resources declared at the Resouce Pool creation time.*/   
    public void testIsFull() throws Exception {
        ResourcePool<SomeResource> resPool = new ResourcePool<SomeResource>(
                SomeResource.class, 5);
        SomeResource[] res = new SomeResource[5];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            res[i] = resPool.acquireResource("A");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            resPool.releaseResource(res[i]);
        }
        assertTrue(resPool.isFull("A"));
        assertFalse(resPool.isEmpty("A"));
    }

    public  void testAcquireBlocksWhenEmpty() throws Exception {
        final ResourcePool<SomeResource> resPool = new ResourcePool<SomeResource>(
                SomeResource.class, 0);
        Thread resourceConsumer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SomeResource unused = resPool.acquireResource("A");
                    fail(); // error if control flow reaches this line
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        };

            resourceConsumer.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000); // waits for the resourceConsumer to block
            resourceConsumer.interrupt();   
            resourceConsumer.join(1000);    // resume after the resourceConsumer ends
            assertFalse(resourceConsumer.isAlive());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

- No need to use synchronization in the constructor - at the moment of creation the object is not yet visible to any concurrent thread.
- Declare a field `Constructor<R> resourceConstructor` and in the constructor, initialize it with `resourceClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class)`. Thus the possible error when there is no such constructor is determined early, and saves time to extract the constructor later. Use it in the method `createResource()`:

  ```
        resource = resourceConstructor.newInstance(str);
  ```
- Rename `num_resource_pools` to `num_resources`, as it actually counts the overall number of resources, not number of pools.
- Create a couple of tests and run them every time the code is modified.